# Continues int value from Data

Tags: c#, integer

I have a question and this problem already make me headache.

So how to make `int i = value` to be continues.

Example I have some int data value = 20, 25, 27, 33.

How to make int being continues changed value step by step to i = 20, i = 25, i = 27, i = 33.

Really this make headache and this case I need `int` result not as `List<int>`.

I hope someone can help me.

I try this:

```
int i == 0;
if(i == 20){ i == 25; }
if(i == 25){ i == 27; }
if(i == 27){ i == 33; }
```

And result show i == 33; not gonna be step by step.

So another try second code:

```
int i == 0;
if(i == 20){ i == 25; }
if(i == 25){ i == 27; }
if(i == 27){ i == 33; }
if(i == 33){ i == 0; }
```

I hope second code looks like loop and repeatedly because I'm noob programmer.

But result i = 0;

Comment: The variable `i` always zero and does not change. Maybe you have to put the initial value `i=20`;

Comment: A side note: `i == 33` etc. is checking for equality, **not** an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` loop to iteratate over an array of values:

```
foreach (var i in new[] { 20,25,27,33 }) 
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: dosen't work its only show first value 20 not being changed to next value or step by step

Comment: Works fine for me; [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PDPSLN)